# Vue.js Passing Data via httpVueLoader

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue instance.

```
var myApp = new Vue({
    el: '#my-App',
    data: {
        user: sessionStorage.getItem('user')
    },
    components: {
        'header-component': httpVueLoader('./components/header-component.vue'),
        'footer-component': httpVueLoader('./components/footer-component.vue')
    }
});
```

And a single file component `header-component`

```
<template>
    <li v-if="user !== ''" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" v-on:click="openProfilePage" href="#">{{user}}</a>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        data: function () {
            return {}
        },
        props: ['user'],
        methods:
            {
                openProfilePage: function () {
                    if (userName !== '') {
                        myApp.page = 'profile';
                        sessionStorage.setItem('page', 'profile');
                        page = 'profile';
                    }
                    else {
                        myApp.page = 'login';
                        sessionStorage.setItem('page', 'login');
                        page = 'login';
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

I don't want to define a new data.user in my single file component and i want to use the data.user of the vue instance. How can i do that? How can i pass this data?

Comment: Pass it as a prop like you would with any other component?

Comment: I tried but i couldn't do that via httpVueLoader. Where should i define the props in instance?

Comment: What do you mean? Define the property on the component, and pass it where it is referenced in `#my-App`.

Comment: Can you show me an example for this situation? i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass it as you would normally pass values from parent to child; using a prop.

Here is an example.

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <test :user="user"></test>
  </div>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        user: "This is a test string"
      },
      components:{
        test: httpVueLoader("/Test.vue")
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

**Test.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>{{user}}
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  props:["user"]
}
</script>
```

This will pass the user defined in the Vue to the Test component and the resulting output will be "This is a test string".

Comment: Is there also a way to pass values from child to parent using only httpvueloader?

Comment: @MK01111000 I don't know.

Comment: @MK01111000 You can use $emit method for this purpose. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201/2

Comment: http-vue-loader doesn't really change anything for passing data. Any method working in vanilla vue-js also works with http-vue-loader. So you can $emit, use ref, a central bus or an object passed by reference, ...